# Determine the number of factors of a large numbers efficiently

Tags: performance, c, mathematics

I am trying to determine the number of factors of a large number efficiently. I have written this function but how can it be improved upon?

```
long numOfFactors(long long n)
{
    long i=0,num=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program actually gives the wrong output for every number. You're forgetting that `n` is a factor of `n`! The easy fix is to simply initialize `num` to 1. Even better to initialize `num` to 2 and start your loop at `i=2`. Once you fix that, your program is fine. It's just that you can just do a lot better performance-wise.

Let's start with the general formula. Any number can be expressed as the product of primes raised to some power: \$n = \prod_i p_i^{k_i}\$. The number of factors of \$n\$ in this case is \$\prod_i(1+k_i)\$. So what we need to do is find all the prime factors.

How do we do that? We can actually reduce `n` as we go. Everytime we find a factor, if we do it right, we can be sure it's prime, so we reduce it as far as possible:

```
exp = 0;
while (n%i == 0) {
    ++exp;
    n /= i;
}
```

So if we're doing `80`, as an example, we will divide by `2` until we're no longer divisible by `2` (that is, `n == 5`). All we have to do then is multiply out all the `exp`s:

```
long numOfFactors(long long n)
{
    long num_factors=1;
    long i;
    long exp;

    for(i=2; i*i<=n; ++i)
    {
        exp=0;
        while (n%i == 0) {
            ++exp;
            n /= i;
        }
        num_factors *= (exp + 1);
    }

    return num_factors * (n > 1 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

The last check is there because if `n>1` at the end, we know it's prime and we haven't counted it yet, so that's another doubling of factors.

Comment: Question: Is it OK that `i` is a `long`, but `n` is a `long long`? Will `i` be promoted to `long long` or could the condition in the `for` loop end up in an infinite loop if `n` is bigger than the max `long`?

Comment: Problems with `i*i<=n`.  `i*i` can overflow `long` math.  Fixing that to `long long i`,  `i*i<=n`  can lead to signed integer overflow should `n` be a large prime.  `i <= n/i` is better.  The cost of the division is often tied to `n%i` so code can do both for the same impact.